# opencart, importing customers

Tags: import, opencart

I have 3 queries regarding this.

I have a new Opencart site and 500+ customers to add. I've found a couple of import customer extensions, but support appears to have gone AWOL and there doesn't seem to be a working version for 1.5.5.1 so I'm looking at importing into mysql with xls files.

My queries are as follows:

Query 1:There seems to be 2 tables I need to upload: (a) Address; and (b) Customer. Are these the only tables that need changing?

Query 2:
I see the passwords are MD5 encrypted. I have passwords for all 500+ customers already - do I have to convert these passwords into MD5, or can I use un-encrypted passwords and the db do the encryption for me?

Query 3:
What do I do about the Salt field in the Customer table? Can I leave this blank?

3 x MTIA !

Comment: Why the close vote? I haven't been able to find anything on how to bulk import customers into Opencart, but there are other people who want to bulk import customers (going by comments on this sort of extension). Surely this is not an invalid SO question.

Comment: circey have you done this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Query 1** : these should be enough (there are other tables like `customer_ip` etc but that should not cause any problem

**Query 2** : database will not encrypt passwords for you

**Query 3** : no you can't leave salt empty (unless you edit the password checking code, which is obviously not recommended)

**so what you should do ?**

**for each customer** first generate salt like this

```
 $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)
```

then encrypt password like this :

```
$password = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)))
```

then save these variables in database.

you can have look at `system/library/customer.php` and `catalog/model/account/customer.php` , to get an idea how things works